# Databricks AnalysisException: Column 'l' does not exist

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I have a very strange occurrence with my code.

I keep on getting the error

```
AnalysisException: Column 'homepage_url' does not exist
```

However, when I do a select with cross Joins the column does actually exist.
Can someone take a look at my cross joins and let me know if that is where the problem is

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  account.xpd_relationshipstatus AS CRM_xpd_relationshipstatus
 ,REPLACE(owneridname,'Data.Import #','') AS xxxxxxx
 ,account.ts_montaguoffice AS Montagu_Office
 ,CAST(account.ts_reminderdatesetto AS DATE) AS testname
 ,CAST(account.ts_lastdatestatuschanged AS DATE) AS YearofCRMtslastdatestatuschanged
 ,organizations.name AS nameCB
 ,organizations.homepage_url
 ,iff(e like 'www.%', e, 'www.' + e) AS website
 ,left(category_list,charindex(',',category_list  +','  )-1) AS category_CB
-- ,case when charindex(',',category_list,0) > 0 then left(category_list,charindex(',',category_list)-1) else category_list end as category_CB
 ,organizations.category_groups_list AS category_groups_CB

FROM basecrmcbreport.account
LEFT OUTER JOIN basecrmcbreport.CRM2CBURL_Lookup
  ON account.Id = CRM2CBURL_Lookup.Key
LEFT OUTER JOIN basecrmcbreport.organizations
  ON CRM2CBURL_Lookup.CB_URL_KEY = organizations.cb_url
cross Join (values (charindex('://', homepage_url))) a(a)
cross Join (values (iff(a = 0, 1, a + 3))) b(b)
cross Join (values (charindex('/', homepage_url, b))) c(c)
cross Join (values (iff(c = 0, length(homepage_url) + 1, c))) d(d)
cross Join (values (substring(homepage_url, b, d - b))) e(e)
```

Without the cross Joins

[image]

Comment: The reason for this is that joins are usually used on tables but not table valued functions. Replace all of them with select statements (or temporary views).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The main reason for cross join (or any join) to recognize the column when you select not when using table valued functions is that **joins are used on tables only**.
- To use table valued functions, one must use `cross apply or outer apply`. But these are not supported in Databricks sql.
- The following is the demo data I am using:

[image]

- I tried using inner join on a table valued function using the following query and got the same error:

```
select d1.*,a from demo1 inner join (values(if(d1.team = 'OG',2,1))) a;
```

[image]

- Instead, using the select query, the joins work as that is how they function:

```
select d1.*,a.no_of_wins from demo1 d1 inner join (select id,case team when 'OG' then 2 when 'TS' then 1 end as no_of_wins from demo1) a on d1.id=a.id;
```

[image]

- So, the remedy for this problem is to replace all the table valued functions on which you are using joins with `SELECT` statements.